# parse std::vector<int> from comma separated integers

Tags: c++, c++11, dsl, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I'm trying to implement a very specific grammar, which requires me  at a certain point to parse a list of comma separated integers. The qi rule looks like the following:

```
qi::rule<Iterator, ascii::space_type> ident;
qi::rule<Iterator, ascii::space_type> nlist;

...

ident = char_ >> nlist;
nlist = ("(" >> int_ % "," >> ")");

...
```

I need to pass the values up to the `ident` rule (The expression ident has to create a syntax tree node, where the parsed values from nlist are required for the constructor). I thought about creating and filling a `std::vector` and use the semantic action like `_val = vector<int>...`. What is now unclear to me is how do I create a vector of arbitrary length from this rule, since I do not make any assumptions  on how long the input will be or using a predefined vector like the [examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/tutorials/number_list___stuffing_numbers_into_a_std__vector.html).

Is this even possible or does is there a better way to do it?

Comment: If you think the resolution is going to be susbtantially different/more complicated because of your supposed expression tree types, you should have included them. All that matters now is that you can use naive attribute propagation to get the vector, and pass that where-ever you wanted to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the bread and butter of Spirit Qi.

Just use any compatible attribute type and profit:

```
    using nlist_t = std::vector<int>;
    using ident_t = std::pair<char, nlist_t>;

    qi::rule<Iterator, ident_t(), qi::ascii::space_type> ident;
    qi::rule<Iterator, nlist_t(), qi::ascii::space_type> nlist;
```

> Note: For `std::pair` attribute compatibility, include the relevant `fusion` header:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5aba3e329f592edf)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main()
{
    using nlist_t = std::vector<int>;
    using ident_t = std::pair<char, nlist_t>;

    using Iterator = std::string::const_iterator;
    qi::rule<Iterator, ident_t(), qi::ascii::space_type> ident;
    qi::rule<Iterator, nlist_t(), qi::ascii::space_type> nlist;

    ident = qi::char_ >> nlist;
    nlist = '(' >> qi::int_ % ',' >> ')';

    for (std::string const input : { "a (1,2,3)", "+(881,-2,42)    \n", "?(0)" }) {

        ident_t data;
        if (qi::phrase_parse(input.begin(), input.end(), ident, qi::ascii::space, data)) {
            std::cout << "Parsed: " << data.first << "(";
            for (auto i : data.second) std::cout << i << ",";
            std::cout << ")\n";
        } else
            std::cout << "Parse failed: '" << input << "'\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
Parsed: a(1,2,3,)
Parsed: +(881,-2,42,)
Parsed: ?(0,)
```

**BONUS**

Version with imagined Ast type using `phoenix::construct`:

**<kbd>[Also Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d7e115e203af4bfa)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace px = boost::phoenix;

namespace OoShinyAst {

    using MyName = char;
    using MyArgument = int;
    using MyArgumentList = std::vector<MyArgument>;

    struct MyIdent {
        MyName         name;
        MyArgumentList args;

        MyIdent() = default;
        MyIdent(MyName name, MyArgumentList args)
            : name(std::move(name)), args(std::move(args)) { }
    };
}

int main()
{
    using Iterator = std::string::const_iterator;
    qi::rule<Iterator, OoShinyAst::MyIdent(),        qi::ascii::space_type> ident;
    qi::rule<Iterator, OoShinyAst::MyArgumentList(), qi::ascii::space_type> nlist;

    nlist = '(' >> qi::int_ % ',' >> ')';
    ident = (qi::char_ >> nlist) [ qi::_val = px::construct<OoShinyAst::MyIdent>(qi::_1, qi::_2) ];

    for (std::string const input : { "a (1,2,3)", "+(881,-2,42)    \n", "?(0)" }) {

        OoShinyAst::MyIdent data;
        if (qi::phrase_parse(input.begin(), input.end(), ident, qi::ascii::space, data)) {
            std::cout << "Parsed: " << data.name << "(";
            for (auto i : data.args) std::cout << i << ",";
            std::cout << ")\n";
        } else
            std::cout << "Parse failed: '" << input << "'\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Version [with imagined Ast type using](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d7e115e203af4bfa) `phoenix::construct` added as a bonus

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution. I did not know that this is possible this way.

Comment: Oldies but goodies: http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/attribute_handling/attribute-propagation-and-attribute-compatibility/, http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/attribute_handling/the-magical-power-of-attributes-in-spirit-primitives/ and more in the same series